# Is this considered a memory leak? If so… how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Millions upon millions of divs with the class .clickable

User becomes a savage and clicks every div in sight

Is this considered a memory leak…

If so…

What code do I need to inject to stop it

```js
var body = $('body');
var clickme = '.clickable';

body.find(clickme).click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $this.addClass($this.data('add-class'));
});
```

```css
/* whatever the class click-number css is suppose to be*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-add-class="click1" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click2" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click3" class="clickable"></div>
…
…
<div data-add-class="click500000" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click500001" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click500002" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click500003" class="clickable"></div>
…
…
<div data-add-class="click1000000" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click1000001" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click1000002" class="clickable"></div>
<div data-add-class="click1000003" class="clickable"></div>
```

Comment: Its exaggerated… but their are a lot of div

Comment: I'd use event delegation in this instance. That would save binding an event listener to each and every div, eg `$(document.body).on('click', '.clickable', function() { this.classList.add(this.getAttribute('add-class')) })`

Comment: Its a web app… and the user creates as many divs as he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue here, and it's not memory leak.

From wikipedia comparing "*memory leak*" against "*space leak*":

> A space leak occurs when a computer program uses more memory than
>   necessary. In contrast to memory leaks, where the leaked memory is
>   never released, the memory consumed by a space leak is released, but
>   later than expected.

If you have millions of divs, the browser will take a noticeable long waiting time to load, and noticeable long waiting time to render, and a noticeable long waiting time to attach event listener on click for each of them.

Your code is fine and don't need to worry about anything. (Unless you truly are using millions of divs).

So to answer your question "Is this considered a memory leak?": **No**.

Comment: It'll be 100,000 lines of html code… and user creates div and add custom classes and custom css to those classes

Comment: I do not have control over their div creativity

Comment: @MonwellPartee That's fine. It will depend on the client's OS and computer specs (RAM and processor). If the web app is consuming too much memory or processing then either: 1- it will be slow and glitchy (but works), 2- or the browser will crash and terminate the tab. If you're afraid of running into such issue, put a limit on how many divs they can create.

Comment: How do I clear out the memory each time the jquery is preformed?

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: @MonwellPartee Simply by deleting the div, the click listener also get detached, like this: `$('#myDiv').remove()`, or you can detach the click listener but keep the div like this: `$('#myDiv').off()`

Answer (score 6):

It's not a memory *leak*, but it is a memory *waste*. User clicking does not matter; the fact that you attach a click listener to every object makes it a waste. Instead, listen on an ancestor element (or `document`, if you can't identify a single common ancestor):

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(evt) {
  ...
});
```

BTW, memory *leak* would be if every time a user clicks, you allocate more memory that you later don't free. You're thankfully not doing that.